# python list comprehension discrepancy setting value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a simple 3d matrix in the following shape. First method works fine as you can see from the output

```
m3d =[[[-1 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
print (m3d)
m3d[0][0][0] = 0
print (m3d)
```

Here is the output

```
[[[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]], [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]], [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]]]
[[[0, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]], [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]], [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]]]
```

However, if I use the shortcut like below

```
m3d = [[[-1]*2]*3]*3
print (m3d)
m3d[0][0][0] = 0
print (m3d)
print ()
```

Output looks like the following. As you can see -1 is set to 0 in all internal arrays. What's going on and how can this be fixed?

`[[[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]], [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]], [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]]]
[[[0, -1], [0, -1], [0, -1]], [[0, -1], [0, -1], [0, -1]], [[0, -1], [0, -1], [0, -1]]]`

Comment: When you build a list like this you are not making new lists — you are making copies of list references so `m3d[0][1] is m3d[0][2]` is `True`!

Comment: Ah that now makes sense. Wonder when would be a need for this method then..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List multiplication is like a shallow copy, and rarely what you want. The new list contains multiple references to the objects in the list being multiplied, so

```
[[-1]*2]*3
```

first evaluates to

```
[[-1,-1]]*3
```

which then creates a list where each of the three elements is a reference to the *same* object, created initially by `[-1]*2`:

```
>>> x = [[-1]*2]*3
>>> id(x[0])
4422292744
>>> id(x[1])
4422292744
>>> id(x[2])
4422292744
```

It does *not* evaluate `[-1]*2` three separate times to get three unique lists.

(`[-1]*2` *also* creates a list where each element is a reference to the same object that represents `-1`, but because `int` values are immutable, it doesn't matter.)

Comment: +1 whenever I see a solution to this reference problem. I remember when I was new to python I spent like 2 hours figuring out what is wrong with my game and I was doing the same mistake like this one. Ohh old days ...